# Do we have enough time for our connection at Heathrow Airport?

Tags: lhr, short-connections

We are flying from Manchester to Heathrow, arriving at 11.05 in Terminal 5. We need to go to Terminal 4 for our 2.15 flight to Doha.

Will the 3 hours be enough time change terminals and get to our next flight, or should we book an earlier flight from Manchester?

Comment: Have you booked it as a single ticket, or through separate purchases?

Comment: Heathrow has a tool to check: http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections it seems to show that you'd need 1:45. It isn't clear to me if this includes collecting checked luggage

Comment: @Miff That tool is showing the minimum connect time for single-PNR journeys. (i.e., no luggage collection.) That said, even on two tickets, three hours is plenty of time to collect bags from a domestic flight and go over to Terminal 4.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Heathrow [flight connection tool](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections) you need 105 minutes.

[image]

Therefore you should be okay.